# calculus of predicted number of failures in cox regression

Tags: cox-model

Suppose we rank the prognosis index (the linear product  beta*X)  of the individuals  in a Cox regression and divide this set in a number G of groups. 
It is trivial to count the number of observed events belonging to every group. But how to calculate the number of expected failures in every group? 
It is not directly feasible  with the survival function for every individual which depends of course upon the time.